# Lipschitz function proof

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Statement**

Let $F(t,X)=A(t)X+b(t)$ with $A(t) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b(t) \in \mathbb R^n$. If the coefficients $a_{ij}(t)$ and $b_i(t)$ are continuous functions of the variable $t$ in a closed and bounded interval $I$, then $F$ is Lipschitz with respect to $X$ in $I \times \mathbb R^n$.

**Attempt of a proof**

Let $K$ be a a positive constant such that $|a_{ij}(t)|\leq K$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$ (we note that such $K$ exists since each $a_{ij}$ is a continuous function on a compact set). Then $$||F(t,X)-F(t,Y)||^2=||A(t)X-A(t)Y||^2$$ $$=||A(t)(X-Y)||^2$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}(t)(x_j-y_j))^2$$

I am trying to find a proper bound for this last expression in order to arrive to an inequality of the form $=||A(t)(X-Y)||\leq C||X-Y||$ for some $C>0$. I would appreciate some help or suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you take the square inside and use $(a_{ij}(x_j-y_j))^2 \leq K^2(x_j-y_j)^2$? The Lipschitz constant $C$ will be something like $Kn$.

Comment: @riem Well, that's my problem, I am not so sure if the inequality $(x_1+...+x_n)^2\leq x_1^2+...x_n^2$ always holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the identity (which follows by Cauchy-Schwarz)
$$(b_1 + ... + b_n)^2 \leq n(b_1^2 + ... + b_n^2)$$
and the rest should follow easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just in case I would like to know if the remaining part is correct (using the property you've suggested): $\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}(x_j-y_j))^2\leq n\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2|x_j-y_j|^2\leq nK^2\sum_{i=1}^n ||X-Y||^2=n^3K^2||X-Y||^2$.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it should be: $n\sum_i\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2|x_j-y_j|^2 \leq nK^2\sum_i\sum_j |x_j-y_j|^2 =n^2K^2\sum_j |x_j-y_j|^2 = n^2K^2|X-Y|^2$.

Comment: I guess yours is right as well, but mine is a tighter bound.

Comment: The last part I've meant $n^3K^2||X-Y|^2$, I've just used the bound you've suggested and then I've used the property $|x_i|\leq ||X||$.

Comment: You used the bound I suggested in the answer in the first inequality. Then you can write $n\sum_i\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2|x_j-y_j|^2 \leq nK^2\sum_i\sum_j |x_j-y_j|^2$ and observe the thing you're summing is independent of $i$, so the $\sum_i$ becomes a multiplicative factor of $n$. Then the sum you're left with is $\sum_j|x_j-y_j|^2$, which is exactly $|X-Y|^2$. What you did instead is use $|x_j-y_j|^2 \leq |X-Y|^2$ for each $j$, which is fine but a bit inefficient because you still have the $\sum_j |X-Y|^2$ left over and the sum part gives you another factor of $n$.